# how to add an xml with 7k+ data in woocommerce database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

i have an erp's database with 7k+ products and i want to add all this data to my eCommerce, someone have an idea how can i import all this data in woo commerce database to sell these products in my website?
 I tried to use an csv file but it failed and turn my website crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you can try to import products with **[WP All Import](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-all-import/)** and **[WooCommerce add-on](https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-xml-csv-product-import/)** for it.

Basic version of WP All Import is free.

If your site crashes during import, you can try to decrease records count per iteration from 20 (by default) to 10 (for example).

[image]